# Mule until-successful to retry only with timeout

Tags: web-services, timeout, mule, esb, timeoutexception

I have put together an until-succesfull in Mule 3.7 (see below):

```
<until-successful maxRetries="100" failureExpression="#[exception != null &amp;&amp; (exception.causedBy(java.net.ConnectException) || exception.causedBy(java.net.SocketTimeoutException)) || message.inboundProperties['http.status'] != 500]" synchronous="true" millisBetweenRetries="20000" doc:name="UntilSuccess">

<processor-chain>

  <set-payload value="#[flowVars.operationPayLoad]" doc:name="GetTransactionRequest" />

  <ws:consumer config-ref="GetTransactionWSConsumerConfig" operation="execute" doc:name="GetTransaction" />
</processor-chain>
```

I am only interested in making the until-successful retry if a web service is down or if it times out. No other exception should be retried by the until-successful.

However, I have done a test where I get a org.mule.module.ws.consumer.SoapFaultException but the until-successful keeps trying to call the web service.

How do I tell the until-successful to ignore all exceptions and stop retrying except for when the web service is down or times out?

Cheers

Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is specified in the MuleSoft documentation, the Until Successful scope will retry if an exception is found or the failure expression is true. The failure expression doesn't override the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of `message.inboundProperties['http.status']` in your test?

Also, try putting parenthesis -

`#[(exception != null && (exception.causedBy(java.net.ConnectException) || exception.causedBy(java.net.SocketTimeoutException))) || message.inboundProperties['http.status'] != 500]`

i.e. (when there is an exception of any of those two types) or status is 500. [Added outer parenthesis to exception check]

Comment: The http status is

Comment: Thanks Manik. The http status is 500. However, the until-successful keeps trying. Maybe I do not understand the function of the failureExpression. I have also tried || message.inboundProperties['http.status'] == 503] but again it keeps retrying.

Comment: Have you tried with parentheses? Failure expression has to return true for until successfully to retry. Try building you condition one at a time and see which one is letting your exception go.

Comment: I have tried <until-successful maxRetries="10" failureExpression="#[true]" synchronous="true" millisBetweenRetries="5000" and <until-successful maxRetries="10" failureExpression="#[false]" synchronous="true" millisBetweenRetries="5000" and in both cases the until-successful keeps retrying.